# Firebase hosting configuration

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

It might be a stupid question but curious to know. I have deployed an Angular app in Firebase hosting which loads the application faster. But whereas the same application deployed in the Windows server takes too long to load.
I would like to know what would be the configuration used in Firebase hosting**(RAM, Memory)**.
From the Firebase docs, I could able to see that it uses **SSD-Backed hosting** but where could i find the other details like how much **RAM** is used and does it uses any CDN.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any configuration for the backend or if the resources are dedicated for a website listed in the documentation. Although it's not just about the server configuration especially since your app is a SPA and is just serving some HTML, JS files, so CDN seems to be making the difference here.

Firebase Hosting does cache your website on a global CDN and hence loading quickly everywhere. I'm not sure if you are using a CDN with your Windows server but if not then the difference sounds obvious (especially if your server is located far away from you). Firebase hosting also serves the files compressed using GZIP or Brotli compression.